# Issue with Error: Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSURL'

Tags: swift, firebase

Im having and Issue On The Line of 
'URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! { (data, response, error) in'

with the Error Code: Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSURL'

I have looked around and different ways to try this and it still gives me an error even with setting the url as a URL type and Not NSURL. If anyone can help that would be amazing! The Code will be down below:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

{
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellID)

    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = user.name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = user.email

    //cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "defaultpropic")
    cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    cell.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true

    if let profileImageUrl = user.profileImageURL
    {
        let url = NSURL(string: profileImageUrl)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! { (data, response, error) in

            //download hit error
            if error != nil
            {
                print(error)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
                    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }

        }).resume()
    }

    return cell
}
```

Area of Fail Below:

```
if let profileImageUrl = user.profileImageURL
    {
        let url = NSURL(string: profileImageUrl)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! { (data, response, error) in //<- Error Here

            //download hit error
            if error != nil
            {
                print(error)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
                    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
```

It supposed to allow me to set a unique profilePic to each user.

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use `NSURL` otherwise you will get another (*Ambiguous reference*) error.

The error occurs because for the *trailing closure* syntax the closing parenthesis after `url!` is missing

```
let url = URL(string: profileImageUrl)
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in ... }
```

You can put the closing parenthesis at the end of the expression but then you have to add the `completionHandler` parameter label

```
let url = URL(string: profileImageUrl)
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in ... })
```